# I want to clear selected data in onClick react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the react-select dropdown what my task is I need to clear the selected field in onClick of reset button mean like if I select on the name in the drop-down it will visible in what I selected so I need to clear the selected field or after clear placeholder filed will visible then again am I am able to select field

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
const [value, setValue]= React.useState('')

const handleSelectChange = (object, action) => {
    let name = action.name;
    let value = object;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
      ...prevFormData,
      [name]: object,
    }));
  };

const handleSelectChangeL = (object, action) => {
    setIndex(data[object.id]);
    setUserlevel(null);
    let name = action.name;
    let value = object.value;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
      ...prevFormData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

const reset = () => {
    setValue('')
  };

                   <Select
                      className="drop-down"
                      options={screenType}
                      name="screen"
                      value={value}
                      onChange={handleSelectChange}
                      placeholder="Screen Type"
                      theme={(theme) => ({
                        ...theme,
                        colors: {
                          ...theme.colors,
                          text: "black",
                          primary25: "#d6fdf7",
                          primary: "#0bb7a7",
                          primary50: "#d6fdf7",
                        },
                      })}
                    ></Select>

                    <Select
                      className="drop-down"
                      options={data?.map((data, index) => ({
                        value: data.username,
                        label: data.username,
                        id: index,
                      }))}
                      name="user"
                      value={data.username}
                      onChange={handleSelectChangeL}
                      placeholder="User Name"
                      theme={(theme) => ({
                        ...theme,
                        colors: {
                          ...theme.colors,
                          text: "black",
                          primary25: "#d6fdf7",
                          primary: "#0bb7a7",
                          primary50: "#d6fdf7",
                        },
                      })}
                    ></Select>

                    <button
                        className="dash-button-1"
                        type="submit"
                        variant="contained"
                        onClick={reset}
                      >
                        Reset
                      </button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to toggle the state of `value` prop in the `<Select>`tag. You may define a state like `const [value, setValue]= useState('')` and change its value based on the `onChange` function.

Your reset function could be like this:

```
const reset = () => {
    setValue('')
  };
```

This will again reset the value of the Select Tag.

Comment: I update my code according to your suggestions but not working you can also see the image after clicking on the reset button its label stay the same

Answer (score 0):

If you will use useEffect then  i think your issue will be resolved.

useEffect(()=>{

},[value])

//i will suggest to store the name in value and then it will work (setValue(data.username))

Comment: can you tell me some example

Comment: Check this Pls https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-chaplygin-y5lqx?file=/src/App.js:0-1181

Comment: @amit kumar I have created this codesandbox and already posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Select `value` field with the state value like below,

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Select from "react-select";

const data = [
  {
    username: "jerry"
  },
  {
    username: "Tim"
  },
  {
    username: "Ravi"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const reset = () => {
    setValue("");
  };

  const handleSelectChange = (selected) => {
    setValue(selected);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        className="drop-down"
        options={data?.map((data, index) => ({
          value: data.username,
          label: data.username,
          id: index
        }))}
        name="user"
        value={value} // <---- CHANGE HERE
        onChange={handleSelectChange}
        placeholder="User Name"
        theme={(theme) => ({
          ...theme,
          colors: {
            ...theme.colors,
            text: "black",
            primary25: "#d6fdf7",
            primary: "#0bb7a7",
            primary50: "#d6fdf7"
          }
        })}
      ></Select>

      <button
        className="dash-button-1"
        type="submit"
        variant="contained"
        onClick={reset}
      >
        Reset
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-chaplygin-y5lqx?file=/src/App.js:0-1181

Comment: ``` const handleSelectChangeL = (object, action) => {
    setIndex(data[object.id]);
    setUserlevel(null);
    let name = action.name;
    let value = object.value;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
      ...prevFormData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };``` I am set like this but if I am setting vale it affecting my other component also

Comment: mean if is set value={value} in another component so whatever i select in first select other component also change with the same value

Comment: Please update codesandbox for reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reset the values of `Select` component we need to define `value` and `onChange` properties like this :

```js
const [value , setValue] = useState([]);

const handleValues = (values): void => setValue(values);

return (
  <Select value={value} onChange={handleValues} />
)
```

And then we can reset the values whenever we need to like this :

```js
setValue([])
```